# Don't find files in explorer file in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I have a **DDMS** problem in my eclipse while i'm trying to learn android ,  that there is no files in file explorer in DDMS ..
What is the wrong ?? 
i tried to restart eclipse but there was no result !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to start an emulator first to see the File Explorer.

Before any emulator is started

[image]

And after an emulator is started click on the emulator name to see

[image]

**Edit**

If you find that the names of the files are not appearing as they should, try doing as in the following image.Click on the down arrow(as shown in image).And then select reset adb.It should close and restart it.If it doesn't restart itself then manually restart again.If still not working, update android sdk tools from your sdk manager.However i would suggest to try [genymotion emulator](http://www.gowthamgts.net/2014/04/slow-android-emulator-here-is.html) for once and see if it works.

[image]

**One more try**

Start task manager then go to processes.There stop adb.exe.Now your adb should stop in eclipse.You can then start the adb again to see if it works.Or you can even stop eclipse.exe and then restart eclipse too, to check if it works.

Comment: the emulator was started .. and i tried to start it again but still no files !!

Comment: Please try creating a new emulator and start that one.Lemme know if it works then.Btw did you click on the emulator name?You need to click on that if it doesn't come automatically.

Comment: the emulator name didn't appear also .. there is no devices in the devices list :// i'll try to create a new one as you say .. 
and i will tell you if it works ..

Comment: Sure, try it.If you are having issues with starting an emulator or creating a new emulator because of slow operations, i would suggest you to use a fast and cool emulator such as [genymotion emulator](http://www.gowthamgts.net/2014/04/slow-android-emulator-here-is.html)

Comment: thaanks a lot ,,it works now .. but still have a little problem with the files in the folders !! their names don't appear !
do you think the problem comes from the emulator speed ??

Comment: everything works fine now ! thanks very very much .. 
and i will try to use the genymotion emulator anyway :))